# Android development - graphical problems / XML

Tags: android, xml

[image: Quick mockup of what I'm looking for]

Hey everyone! I'm new to android development and I'm having some problems getting my layout set the way I would like. I'm experienced with Java and Object Oriented design, but my markup/graphical skills could use some work.

Attached is roughly what I'm trying to accomplish. Its going to be a basic game -the reds are ImageViews, blues are buttons, and the green is a label. Things I need help with:

-The Images are very small on high pixel density screens. Can I make it so that the images scale to a certain percentage of the screen, no matter what the device is? I realize that the image may be distorted - this is okay. The quality of these images isn't too important.

-How should I approach the gap between the ImageViews and the Label?

Any other suggestions or code on how to work with this are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems simple enough. Note my solution below is done all in xml.

First thing is you will need all the assets in different screen densities-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. You can skip ldpi if you're not targeting super small phones. Of course xxhdpi assets would be the highest resolution and ldpi (or mdpi if you skip ldpi) assets would be lowest resolution. Note that Android has specific guidelines for the ratio between the different dpis. That is, mdpi icons are 'X' times the size of ldpi icons, etc etc. You can google the ratios and obtain the assets in the different densitites (dpi).

Now create separate drawable folders for each asset type. You need to name them as: drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc. Place the ldpi assets in the drawable-ldpi folder, mdpi in drarable-mdpi, etc etc.

Now, more than likely you will NOT need to create different layouts for different screens but I'll get to it in a bit.

The way I would do it is break up the screen in 4 relative layouts-2 for the red image views, 1 for green label, and 1 for blue buttons. Anchor your blue relative layout to the bottom of the screen using android:layoutAlignParentBottom = true. Now within the blue relative layout, to place the 5 buttons, I would use a TableLayout and put that in the blue relative layout. Now, start adding each button as TableRow item. They will automatically be evenly placed but I would recommend giving each button a padding with android:padding = "X dip" (set X).

Now set the green label layout on top of the blue relative layout. Add the label in it.

Now set the red relative layout (that has two images) on top of the green layout and stack is so that the bottom is aligned with the top of green relative layout and top is aligned with the bottom of 1st row red relative layout. Add a TableLayout and add the two images. To make them closer to the top, align the TableLayout to the top of the 2nd row Relative Layout and give a padding to push the icons by whatever dip padding you give.

Now, stack the 1st red relative layout bottom on top of the 2nd row relative layout. Set the top of the 1st red relative layout to the top of the screen using android:alignParentTop = true. Now add another TableLayout here and add the 3 images as TableRow items with appropriate padding.

Doing everything in relation to the blue relative layout which is anchored to the bottom of the screen, will ensure symmetry. And using different density graphics will appropriately increase the size of the assets within.

This way you can get away with having just one layout folder. However, one caveat is that on some screens, it may not look just the way you want it. If it does happen, then you create a separate layout for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different layout folders (layout, layout-large etc) for different screen density and give imageview sizes (width & height) accordingly in each layout. Follow the link below to understand more:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
I recommend you to use linear layout with weights. as weights divide each screen equally
and as you are using HD graphics,no need to create diffrent folders.but if you want to
 use different folders the you have to use layout folder for screen size upto 5.1 inch
 and layout-sw600dp-land and port for 7"  and layout-sw720dp-land and port for 10 inch.
```